# Date picker dialog date validation

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, android-datepicker

I would like to implement the following behaviour:

- When today's date is `less than 15`, `1-15` date is enabled in date Picker
- When today's date is `greater than 15`, `16-31` date is enabled in date picker

My code is:

```
private void DateDialog() {
    final DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,android.app.AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //int curyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cal.set(i, i1, i2);
            etsubmstartdate.setText(dateformatter.format(cal.getTime()));
            selecteddate = dateformatter.format(cal.getTime());
            Log.e("Date of first edit text",selecteddate);
            etsubmstartdate.setText(selecteddate);
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    if (System.currentTimeMillis()<=15)
    {
        dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
        dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now+(1000*60*60*24*15));
        dpDialog.show();
    }
    else if(System.currentTimeMillis()>=15)
    {
        dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60*60*24*2);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60*60*24*2;
        dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now+(1000*60*60*24*14));
        dpDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please read again your question, its unclear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895071/how-to-validate-date-picker)

Comment: You mean rest of half of the month days will be disabled if the current date is 15.

Comment: first check your current date, If current date is less than 15 then set min and max date in date picker, It will automatically enable and disabel according to your min and max date.

Comment: @farhana You mean `dpDialog.getDatePicker.setMinDate()` and `.setMaxDate()`? That sounds viable. But this is already done in the code in the question!? So what are you suggesting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **.before** and **.after** methods of **Date class**.

For example,

```
if (currentDate.before(yourdate)) {

//write your code require to before current date
}

if (currentDate.after(yourdate)) {

//write your code require to after current date
}
```

As per your code please replace below code in **DateDialog() method**

```
private void DateDialog() {

 final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                          int dayOfMonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        updateLabel();
                    }

                };

                DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "date::"+myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String dt = "2018-04-15";
                String dtSixteen = "2018-04-16";

                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
                try {
                    Date dateFifteen = format.parse(dt);
                    Calendar calFifteen = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calFifteen.setTime(dateFifteen);

                    Date dateSixteen = format.parse(dtSixteen);
                    Calendar calSixteen = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calSixteen.setTime(dateSixteen);


                    Date currentDate = myCalendar.getTime();
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                    calendar.setTime( myCalendar.getTime() );
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                    currentDate = calendar.getTime();


                    if(currentDate.before(dateFifteen) || currentDate.equals(dateFifteen)){
                        dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calFifteen.getTimeInMillis());
                    }else {
                         dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calSixteen.getTimeInMillis());
                    }

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dpDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: it's not working for me before and after is not visible in my suggestion menu

Comment: what is your suggestion menu? and **before and after** are methods of **Date class ** as i mentioned above

Comment: means date ke before and after  method show nhi ho rhe

Comment: hi @RAJKUMAR I have edited new code as per your requirement pleas try it and let me know if any query.

Comment: mam you take static date in your above code but i want this operation on every month

Comment: yeah @Raj kumar. you can change as per your requirement its just demo for you and after added this code you can apply your logic for every month. but after and before method its work properly Right?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested, but something like the following.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
    LocalDate min;
    LocalDate max;
    if (today.getDayOfMonth() < 16) {
        min = today.withDayOfMonth(1);
        max = today.withDayOfMonth(15);
    } else {
        min = today.withDayOfMonth(16);
        max = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    }

    DatePicker picker = dpDialog.getDatePicker();
    picker.setMinDate(min.atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    picker.setMaxDate(max.atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli());

    dpDialog.show();
```

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. While you’re at it, you may substitute your use of the age-old `Calendar` class and friends with the modern classes too. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

I am hesitating to use the device time zone setting through `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but since the date picker relies on it, I found no way around it. The setting may be changed at any time by another part of your program, leading to unpredictable results.

### What went wrong in your code?

Comparing `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the value 15 won’t work. The method gives you a count of milliseconds since the epoch of January 15, 1970 at 00:00 UTC. Current values are around 1 524 000 000 000. So always much greater than 15.

Whether your time math is correct I haven’t checked. I find it quite cumbersome to do such math myself in the code. I much prefer to leave it to well-tested library methods. It’s much less error-prone it allows for much clearer code.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Sorry to hear, @RAJKUMAR. If you quote the error message you get, I’ll see if I can figure out what to do about it.

Comment: I thought I had, @RAJKUMAR. I don’t have Android Studio, so cannot test and debug.